# How to run cucumber scenarios alongside other type of tests?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have some cucumber scenarios running smoothly, but I want to run other type of tests too. Like, "test each component on the page" is not a valid scenario, because BDD is made to check behaviours.
I wanted to divide cucumber scenarios AND selenium/components tests

Here's my runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/test/features/"},            
        glue = {"test.steps"},        
        tags = {""},        
        plugin = {"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" +
                "path"}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cucumber tests will run at the same time as your other unit tests (*Test) or integration tests (*IT) during your build, depending on the name of your runner (which is missing from your code snippet).

Depending on whether you are using Cucumber to assert behaviour on a unit test level, or integration test level, name your runner `RunCucumberTest` or `RunCucumberIT` respectively.

For example (using the options you provided):

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/test/features/"},            
        glue = {"test.steps"},        
        tags = {""},        
        plugin = {"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" +
                "path"}
)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: So, should I put all the @Test methods within "RunCucumberTest" and it would work as unit tests everytime it has been built?

Comment: You do not need to use the `@Test` annotation with Cucumber. You can specify your unit/integration test with your unit testing framework (e.g. JUnit) in separate classes. If you are using Maven, all classes ending with *Test or *IT will be run by surefire and failsafe plugin respectively

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I still don't get it: _"You can specify your unit/integration test with your unit testing framework (e.g. JUnit) in separate classes"_ How? I'm not tend to use Cucumber to assert behaviour on a unit test level because I believe this is not the purpose of BDD. What I wanted are methods to check if everything's ok, and the cucumber running independently

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is you don't use Cucumber for your unit tests. It will run independently. What is the problem you are currently having in your build?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thank you!